# Error invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c, cs50

I've been working on readability in cs50 and I am really stuck as to what I've done wrong/what I'm missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int sentences = 0;
    int numberOfCharacters = strlen(text);
    string characters[numberOfCharacters];
    int words = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i == numberOfCharacters; i++) {
        if (isspace(characters[i]) == 0) {
            words ++;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < numberOfCharacters; i++) {
        if (text[i]=='.') {
            numberOfCharacters++;
        }
    }

    int averageWords = characters / words * 100;

    int index = 0.0588 * round(characters) - 0.296 * round(sentences) - 15.8;

    printf("Grade %d \n", index);
}
```

The error I get from that, using help50, is: `readability.c:26:35: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('string [numberOfCharacters]' and 'int')`

Comment: Look closely at this line: `int averageWords = characters / words * 100;`. What is the type of `characters`?

Comment: `string characters[numberOfCharacters];` looks wrong, because `string text = get_string("Text: ");` seems to define `string` as `char *` or similar, so `char *characters[numberOfCharacters];` would be giving you an array of strings, not a string

Comment: The error has nothing to do with readability, so please choose a better title.

Comment: Your word counting will be wrong unless your string ends with a space because you only ever increment `words` when you find a space.  Also if there are two spaces in a row it will count two words.  As a practical use case think of a dash surrounded by spaces - a dash shouldn't count as a word, should it?

Comment: You don't really want either of the loops looping through `characters` because characters is an output for the program - you want to loop through `text` instead, don't you?.  Also, in the second loop you use `numberOfCharacters` as the loop condition but also increment `numberOfCharacters` to keep track of what you found - those two things need to be separate variables...  Ok, wait.  When you `int averageWords = characters / words * 100;` that implies that `characters` is an int and not an array at all.  There is something wrong.

Comment: What is your expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cs50 `string` is a `typedef` of `char*`, so what you have there is:

```
char *characters[numberOfCharacters];
```

Which is an array of pointers, they are not initialized in any way, in your next statements you accessing these unitialized values and you are passing an incompatible argument to `isspace`.

Furthermore, the expression:

```
 int averageWords = characters / words * 100;
```

Is odd, you're dividing an array of pointers to `char` (wich decays to a pointer, but that's beside the point), by an `int`. That's where the error stems from, but you need to correct the rest.

Not to mention `round(characters)` which is also very strange, that function expects a `double` argument, but again, you are passing to it an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

#### First Issue:

`string` is defined as `char *` so this is wrong:

```
string characters[numberOfCharacters];
```

That is giving you an array of strings, not a string of length `numberOfCharacters`

Change that to this:

```
char characters[numberOfCharacters];
```

#### Second Issue:

`characters` is uninitialized when first used, you could of meant to use `text` instead in the loop

#### Third Issue:

Performing math (`round(characters)` and `characters / words * 100`) on a string or array is certainly wrong and makes no sense, so I am not sure what you are *attempting* to do here

I reviewed the clear issues, but since it is unclear what your program is trying to do, I cannot provide further feedback

Answer (score 1):

The name `string` is defined as an alias for the type char *. So this declaration

```
string characters[numberOfCharacters];
```

is equivalent to the declaration

```
char * characters[numberOfCharacters];
```

So in this expression

```
isspace(characters[i]) == 0
```

the argument `characters[i]`  has the type `char *` while the function expects an argument of the type `int`.

So you need at least to  declare

```
char characters[numberOfCharacters];
```

But in any case this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i == numberOfCharacters; i++) {
    if (isspace(characters[i]) == 0) {
        words ++;
    }
}
```

does not make a sense because the array `characters` was not initialized.

It seems within this loop you were going to use `text` instead of `characters`.

This expression

```
int averageWords = characters / words * 100;
```

is entirely wrong and does not make a sense. You are trying to divide a pointer ( after implicit conversion the array characters to a pointer to its first element) by an integer. But such an operation is not defined for pointers.

So it is unclear what the program does.